# How to implement MenuItem in Xamarin Forms - Shell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am programming an app and would like to implement two menuItems within a shell. The problem is that I just get black background when I start the app. Thank you very much !!!

[image]

Here is the XAML File from Shell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.MainShell"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    BackgroundColor="#9da7d6"
    IconImageSource="NoWifiPic">

    <MenuItem Text="Rate" IconImageSource="RatingStar.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"/>
    <MenuItem Text="Support" IconImageSource="Feedback.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked_1"/>

</Shell>
```

Here is the Code File from Shell:

```
public partial class MainShell : Shell
    {
        public MainShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

      
      
        private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code
        }

        private async void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Code
        }
    }
```

Here is the Code File from App:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MainShell();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
         
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
          
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you solved it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ,it is starting with `Page1`. Change it to your own page that you want to start with.

```
<ShellItem Route="Startpage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="home" />
</ShellItem>
```

After this you can add the MenuItems

```
 <ShellItem Route="Startpage">
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" Route="home" />
</ShellItem>

<MenuItem Text="Rate" IconImageSource="RatingStar.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"/>
<MenuItem Text="Support" IconImageSource="Feedback.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked_1"/>
```

Here the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/

If You want to `hide` the `Startpage or HomePage` button in the Flyout use this

```
FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
```

Add this to the ShellItem.

```
  <ShellItem Route="Startpage" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" >
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="home"/>
</ShellItem>


<MenuItem Text="Rate" IconImageSource="RatingStar.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"/>

<MenuItem Text="Support" IconImageSource="Feedback.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked_1"/>
```

Startpage :

[image]

Comment: Hello Bas H thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the solution contains ShellItem with Start from Page1 and with that I still get a button I don't need. I only need two buttons. Yes but otherwise the app starts with it without problems but this is not the solution I need

Comment: @Yves i added 2 images , the first is how the App starts and the 2e image is the Flyout with 2 buttons . I this not what you want ? You don't see the Page1 Button

Comment: Found it here in the Documentation . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-visibility

Answer (score 1):

Any MenuItem objects declared before FlyoutItem objects will appear before the FlyoutItem objects in the flyout, and any MenuItem objects declared after FlyoutItem objects will appear after the FlyoutItem objects in the flyout.

We could not only add the MenuItem. We need a ShellContent to show the default page when you open the app except the MenuItem. But we could hide it like [@Bas H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867491/bas-h) said with the `FlyoutItemIsVisible` property.

```
 <FlyoutItem FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"  x:Name="aboutItem">
    <ShellContent Title="Test2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}"></ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
<MenuItem Text="Rate" IconImageSource="tab_about.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"/>
<MenuItem Text="Support" IconImageSource="tab_about.png" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"/>
```

[image: strong text]

If you set the `FlyoutItemIsVisible` to false and still see the button as screenshot, you could try to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: Thank you. Its was also helpfull